# Getting disk drive info incorrectly

Tags: c#

```
public static string GetDriveType()
{
    DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

    foreach (DriveInfo drive in allDrives) 
    {
        return DriveInfo.DriveType;

        if(DriveType.CDRom)
        {
            return DriveInfo.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

As you guys can probably see, there is quite a bit wrong with this code. Basically, I am trying to return the name of the drive to use later in the code, but only if the drive is a CDRom drive. How can I just check the name of the drive and return it so that I can interpret it later when I am programmatically opening the CD drive? Thanks!

Comment: Your question is trivial, the example code a non conclusive piece of confusion (multiple return statements) which means the question in total is unclear.

Comment: The question sums up my request completely. I'm just wondering how I can check for specific types of the drives and return them to be used later.

Comment: `// return DriveInfo.DriveType;`

Comment: Start by figuring out if you want a Drive or all Drives.

Answer (score 1):

You should return a list of strings in case there are more cd drives:

```
public static List<string> GetCDDrives()
{
    var cdDrives =  DriveInfo.GetDrives().Where(drive => drive.DriveType == DriveType.CDRom);

    return cdDrives?.Select(drive => drive.Name).ToList();
}
```

Comment: IMHO, the best answer ( c#6)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need something like the following:

```
public static string GetCDRomName()
{
    // Get All drives
    var drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
    var cdRomName = null;

    // Iterate though all drives and if you find a CdRom get it's name 
    // and store it to cdRomName. Then stop iterating.
    foreach (DriveInfo drive in allDrives) 
    {
        if(drive.DriveType == DriveType.CDRom)
        {
            cdRomName = drive.Name;
            break;
        }
    }

    // If any CDRom found returns it's name. Otherwise null.
    return cdRomName;
}
```

Comment: I'll test it in the morning, but this looks like a working code. My mistake was improperly using return statements. I really only need one. This should work out fine, thanks!

Comment: @TAYLORBROWN you are welcome. I am glad that I helped :)